# Where do I add custom verification for user registration

Tags: laravel

I have a custom regitration form where I need (users telephone number and company id) as well as email and password.
The telephone number and company id will get an api call to verify its existence in the comapny directory.  If it passes then I need to allow User model to make the registration but if it fails then return a fail.

Q: where in the chain of registration should I make this api call to allow/reject the registration?

my `\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php` looks like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf
                        
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="companyid" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Innovations ID</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="companyid" type="text" class="form-control" name="companyid" value="" required autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="telephonenumber" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Zip Code</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="telephonenumber" type="text" class="form-control" name="telephonenumber" value="" required autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`
I would think this is where I would add my api call but not sure how to go about it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller{

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data){
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'companyid' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'telephonenumber' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'companyid' => $data['companyid'],
            'telephonenumber' => $data['telephonenumber'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

this is my user model `app\User.php`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'companyid', 'telephonenumber', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in the `create` method of the RegisterController.

You can make api calls within create method using the `Http` facade. But you need to have guzzle as dependency in your project. You can pull it using composer.

```sh
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Then you can make the api calls

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //Remember to import the use statement
    //use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; at top

    $response = Http::get('http::/example.com');

    //Need to stop further execution by throwing an exception
    //If the verification via api call fails
    //abort_unless($response->verified = true, 419);
    
    return User::create([
        'companyid' => $data['companyid'],
        'telephonenumber' => $data['telephonenumber'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests

Comment: Yes Guzzle is an Http client https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: i am testing the part `Need to stop further execution` and placed `return redirect()->route('error-page');` and commented out `return User::create([])` but the redirect does not work,  do you know how to correctly redirect?

Comment: You need to throw an exception to break/stop the execution. The pipeline of execution warrants an exception to be thrown to stop further execution. Returning anything like false or redirect won't work.

Comment: you have forgotten to write method like get in `Http::('http::/example.com');`

Comment: Thanks @bhucho for caching the omission, fixed now